# What is "cr" in the usage of the gears.shape.rounded_rect, and how can I use this to alter the shape of naughty.notify?

Tags: awesome-wm

I am attempting to reshape a naughty.notify notification from a rectangle to a rectangle with rounded corners. [Here](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/libraries/naughty.html#notify) I'm told that the shape argument takes a `gears.shape` argument—so I look [here](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/libraries/gears.shape.html) to see how to use `gears.shape.rounded_rect`. Every example shows something like this: `shape.rounded_rect(cr, 70, 70, 10`, but the only place I can find that gives any information about what `cr` is says "cr: A cairo content".

What is a cairo content?

This is the code I'm using:

```
naughty.notify({    text = "Monitor Test", ontop = true, position = "bottom_left", 
                    shape = gears.shape.rounded_rect(cr, 70, 20, 5),
                    opacity = .95})
```

Naturally, I get an error when restarting Awesome, because `cr` isn't anything. I've tried everything from a number to cr:fill, but I just don't know what's supposed to go there.

Does anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Cairo is a 2D graphic library used by Awesome. You might want to have a look [here](https://elv13.github.io/documentation/16-using-cairo.md.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've search for this quite a lot and didn't find an answer that can easily be put to use. ploth's link is a really good read. The easy answer is that anywhere that you can set `shape`, you can pass a function and call the shape you want. The function you pass to `shape` will receive `(cr, width, height)` and you can pass those to the shape you want. For example:

```
wibox.container.background(widget, "#000", function(cr, width, height)
  gears.shape.partially_rounded_rect(cr, width, height, false, true, true, false, 30)
end)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, [define a function like this](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/libraries/gears.shape.html), which ill have `cr` as a placeholder:

example:

```
local new_shape = function(cr, width, height)
    gears.shape.rounded_rect(cr, width, height, 2)
end
```

Then just use `new_shape` as shape. (`cr` is defined on the function signature above, line 1, so it is already defined in line 2, and will be filled with the correct value by the callback when `new_shape` is called. You don't define it in `rc.lua` yourself, just leave it empty.)

use new_shape like this:

```
    local noti = naughty.notify {
    position = "top_middle",
    height = 20,
    width = 70,
    timeout = 1,
    shape = new_shape, --SEE HERE
    bg="#333333",
    fg="#ffffff",
    text = "TEST",
}
```